# Retrieve columns that has only 'yes' value and not column that has both 'yes' and 'no' value

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my table

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 02/03/50 | y |
| 02/03/50 | n |
| 05/06/80 | n |
| 07/08/91 | y |

I want to retrieve both column with col2 = 'y' only, i.e. 07/08/91.

It should not retrieve 02/03/50 because it has both Y and N.

Comment: `col1` may have duplicates (it already does in your sample data). Can you have multiple rows (more than one) with the same `col1` value, all having `Y` in the `col2` column? If so, do you need to return **all** the rows from the input, or only one copy of the row? Going beyond what you showed: are there, in fact, other columns too, with additional data? And do you need to retrieve ALL that additional data, for all the rows that meet your condition?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `col2` is not nullable, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1 AND t2.col2 = 'N'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the first column, use aggregation.  If the second column only takes on `'Y'` and `'N'`, you can use:

```
select col1
from t
group by col1
having min(col2) = 'Y';
```

This uses the fact that `'Y' > 'N'`.  If the column had more values, you could use instead:

```
select col1
from t
group by col1
having min(case when col2 = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end) = 0;
```